# Which DHCP is assigning IP addresses to WSL machines?

Tags: centos7, ip, dhcp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run CentOS 7 inside WSL on Windows 11.

My WSL IP is:

```
[root@rbarak ~]# ip addr | grep eth0
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.23.28.162/20 brd 172.23.31.255 scope global eth0
```

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-07-CF-F2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::94a6:887d:821b:abf4%51(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.16.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 855643485
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-29-94-A2-29-A0-29-19-7A-2C-5D
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I connect to the net via WiFi, and my Wifi IP is in another range:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : corp.voxter.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4C-03-4F-D7-3B-E2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9d84:da06:3969:9622%22(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.42.113(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, 4 July, 2022 09:04:42
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, 11 July, 2022 14:45:46
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.42.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.42.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 172753743
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-29-94-A2-29-A0-29-19-7A-2C-5D
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.206.0.8
                                       10.206.0.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

My CentOS networking is:

```
[root@rbarak ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
BOOTPROTO="none"
ONBOOT="yes"
PREFIX="24"
TYPE="Ethernet"
USERCTL="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6INIT="no"
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT="1"
```

The address I'm assigned by DHCP clashes with another IP address, so — my question is, which DHCP is assigning IP addresses to WSL machines, or in other words, which configuration files do I need to change to be assigned an address in a different range (e.g., 192.168.100.2)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior of the Default virtual switch in Hyper-V in Windows 10. I know mothing about WSL, but if your CentOS instance is a VM running in Hyper-V you should be able to create a new external virtual switch, which should allow your CentOS VM to acquire it's ip configuration from your DHCP server, rather than from the Hyper-V host.